# Unity - Oculus Main camera position change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

I can change the MainCamera position to follow the object in Desktop mode, but its not working with Oculus Rift.

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, myobj.transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 70), Time.deltaTime * 10);
        Vector3 relativePos = myobj.transform.position - transform.position;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos);
        transform.rotation = rotation;
```

How do I change it with Oculus Rift ?

Comment: Do not rotate the oculus camera via code, this is one of the fastest ways to induce motion sickness. You can translate the root object, but never rotate it.

Answer (score 0):

[Unity Docs on VR](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VROverview.html)

The headset will overwrite the position of the main camera. That's why you can't modify its position or rotation.